# How do I truncate a long unordered list with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, truncate, html-lists

I am using wordpress to display a list of categories, sorted alphabetically. I want to use jQuery to append a "read more" link after the first 20 links. When the user clicks "read more" the rest of the categories slide down/appear. The HTML format of the list is below:

```
<ul id="catA">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <li class="cat-item">
        <a title="title" href="#">Category Name</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item">
        <a title="title" href="#">Category Name</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item">
        <a title="title" href="#">Category Name</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want the `<a href="#">view all categories</a>` to be appended to the list after the 20rh category, and hiding everything after that. Before I attempt to write some code, any thoughts on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution, but may work:

- Let the 'view all' link created after the list, and give it an ID like '#catA-viewall';
- Hide all items;
- Show only the first 20;
- On click on 'view all', we show all the elements.

  ```
  var $items = $('#catA').children();
  if ( $items.length > 20 ) {
      $items.hide().slice(0, 20).show();
      $('#catA-viewall').click(function () {
          $items.fadeIn(); // or .show()
          $(this).remove();
      });
  } else {
      $('#catA-viewall').remove();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I would find the 20th li element using the [:eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (noting that it is *zero-indexed*), add your View All link after it, then make use of the [:gt() selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to select and hide your extra li elements. You would need to attach an event handler to your View All link that shows the hidden li's and removes itself.

Comment: didn't know about the gt selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
$('ul#catA').children('li').each(function (i)
{
    if (i > 19)
    {
        $(this).hide();   
    }
});

var more = $('<li class="cat-item"><a href="">Show More</a></li>');
$('ul#catA').append(more);

more.find('a').on('click', function (){
   $(this).parent().siblings('li').show();

   return false; 
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WreD/) showing my method in action.

---

I created an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WreD/2/) based on @nachito's recommendation on using the `:gt()` selector.  I also added some comments explaining what's happening.

```
// creating the new 'Show More' link
var more = $('<li class="cat-item"><a href="">Show More</a></li>');

// hiding all lis after the first two
$('ul#catA').children('li:gt(1)').hide();

// adding the 'Show More' link
$('ul#catA').append(more);

// binding a click event to 'Show More'
more.find('a').on('click', function (){        
   // hiding 'Show More' and showing the rest of the lis in this ul 
   $(this).parent().hide().siblings('li').show();

   // preventing default action and event bubbling
   return false; 
});
```

Comment: great method, sometimes I wish I could select two good answers. Thanks!